# Binding Properties and using them during lengthy operations

Tags: multithreading, javafx

In my JavaFX Application I want to disable a couple of Buttons during a refresh of the data from a database.

I am using the `disableProperty` of the Buttons I want to disable.

Here is the basic JavaFX Application, modefied to illustrate my point:

```
public class BindLengthy extends Application {

BooleanProperty disable = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.disableProperty().bind(disable);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            disable.set(true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BindLengthy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            btn.setText("Done");
        }
    });

    //Do all the other stuff that needs to be done to launch the application
    //Like adding btn to the scene and so on...
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

When executed, on the click the Button stays in the "fired" mode, waits for 5 Seconds and then changes text and disables. While I want the text to change later, I want to disableProperty Change to take effect immediately!

I tried putting the lengthy operation, represented by `Thread.sleep(5000)` into a task and start it on a `new Thread(task)`, but then obviously the text is changes before the Thread awakens.

I can't put the `btn.setText("Done")`into the `Thread`as it wouldn't be executed on the `JavaFX-Thread`(which it needs to). So I tried joining the Thread, yet that gives the same result as not putting it into an extra Thread as well.

**How can I force the `diableProperty` to register the new value before executing my long operation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Task` and use its `onSucceeded` handler to update the UI:

```
public class BindLengthy extends Application {

    BooleanProperty disable = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.disableProperty().bind(disable);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                disable.set(true);

                Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        return "Done" ;
                    }
                });

                task.setOnFailed(e ->
                    Logger.getLogger(BindLengthy.class.getName())
                          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, task.getException()));

                task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
                    btn.setText(task.getValue());
                    disable.set(false);
                });

                Thread t = new Thread(task);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.start();
            }
        });

        //Do all the other stuff that needs to be done to launch the application
        //Like adding btn to the scene and so on...
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Had the same approach but forgot to remove a `btn.setText("Done")` underneath `thread.start();`... No surprise it did update that text right away.
But what do I need the `thread.setDaemon(true)` for?

Comment: Making the thread a daemon thread means it will not prevent the application from exiting. (Try pressing the button and immediately exiting the application. Try that again without setting the thread as a daemon thread.) See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).